# C# loop string array error

Tags: c#

Ok I am confused by this, I have: a int variable a string array and a statement that all should would. Its pretty standard looping array structure.

```
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{

    public int ticker = 0;
    public string[] pictureArray = new String[] {
            "image01.jpg",
            "image02.jpg",
            "image03.jpg",
            "image04.jpg",
            "image05.jpg",
            "image06.jpg",
            "image07.jpg",
            "image09.jpg",
            "image10.jpg",
            "image11.jpg",
            "image12.jpg",
            "image13.jpg",
            "image14.jpg",
            "image15.jpg",
            "image16.jpg",
            "image17.jpg",
            "image18.jpg",
            "image19.jpg",
            "image20.jpg",
            "image21.jpg",
            "image22.jpg"
        };
...
        if (this.ticker < 21)
        {
            this.ticker++;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ticker = 0;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(pictureArray[ticker]);
```

It runs fine until ticker is > 21 then it crashes and states IndexOutOfRange but if I were to say change the MessageBox to just print ticker it is fine and I have no error. Now I have looked through similar questions but the problem is that I am a PHP programmer and I am not sure on some of them if the answers pertain to my situation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I think that I have all of the relevant information here if not I apologize. But everything works until it starts to recycle the array and run through the array again. I am just baffled.

Comment: Where does `this.ticker` come from? Also, sure you don't want `if (this.ticker < pictureArray.Length)`

Comment: While you state you are a PHP programmer, I believe the answer is staring you right there in the face. Arrays are indexed starting at 0 to max items. So if you read max items + 1 (e.g. `this.ticker`), then you get an IndexOutOfRange Exception. Change it to <= 21.

Comment: What is the value of `ticker` when the exception is thrown? Is it thrown from `pictureArray[ticker]` line? This code look fine to me.

Comment: @Brad - `ticker` is a field in the form. Look at the top of the class.

Comment: You have a 22 items. First has index 0, and the last one - 21.

Comment: @Code Monkey - I think you're wrong - there are 22 items (indexes from 0 to 21) so changing the condition would set the `ticker` to 22.

Comment: @Jakub nope, theres 21. Look at Jon's answer. The file names are lying!

Comment: that's weird! why is that giving you IndexOutOfBounds? do you also get this error if you change the condition to this.ticker <20

Comment: @Jakub: Count them by hand. There are 21 items indexed from 0 to 20. He also increments his counter before showing any elements so he always skips 0, thus out of bounds.

Comment: @Jakub: Touche, in an effort to scroll down it scrolled the code window as well, didn't catch first line. ;-)

Comment: @Code Money - you're right! image names are 1 based ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing `image08.jpg`, which means there are only 21 entries in your array, not 22. Therefore when `ticker` is 21, you'll get an exception.

One way of making this more robust is to use:

```
if (ticker < pictureArray.Length - 1)
{
    ticker++;
}
else
{
    ticker = 0;
}
```

Or with a conditional:

```
ticker = ticker < pictureArray.Length - 1 ? ticker : 0;
```

Or with Richard's "unconditional increment, conditional reset".

Or possibly the somewhat simpler:

```
ticker = (ticker + 1) % pictureArray.Length;
```

Admittedly in this case that would cause you to miss what I suspect is the real problem - you haven't got all the images you're expecting to have.

Comment: and he increments the array before showing the first element so he always skips 0.

Comment: OMG! I have been looking at this for an hour trying to figure it out I can not believe it was that simple and stupid thanks man.

Comment: Won't this cause an IndexOutOfRangeException? You'll get to a point where ticker is equal to length and therefore out of range. (That's why I did the ticker++ outside of the if statement)

Comment: @Code Monkey yea it was the reverse it got moved around when I was trying to figure out what was going on. thanks though.

Comment: @Brandon: Also keep in mind where you are incrementing that index.

Comment: @Richard: Yes - have added a `- 1` :) I prefer the one-liner though.

Answer (score 2):

If ticker = 20, you click it up to 21.

Then you try to index a 0 based 21 element array at position 21.

Your if should be `ticker < 20`

Edit -

Ha, looks like while this would fix your index problem, Jon's answer is the correct one.

That's pretty funny.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to do this:

```
MessageBox.Show(pictureArray[ticker]);

ticker++;
if (ticker >= pictureArray.Length)
{
    ticker = 0;
}
```

This way it will also adapt if you change the size of pictureArray.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never read index 0 at all. In the first instance, you increment `this.ticker` before reading the first element. You should increment after displaying the value of the string at each array position.

So ultimately, what ends up happening is you set your index to `21` and not `20` thus `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have 21 items you are missing image08.jpg!! so you should change the condition to < 20 . Or in general  `< PictureArray.Length - 1`

Comment: wooo!! I didn't notice people posted 4 answers so fast! +1 everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

BrandonS, the problem with your code is very minute but results badly.
Flow of your code :

1. First you are checking the value of ticker
2. If it is less, you increment to 1, else make it 0
3. You print the value of array

So, 
    public string[] pictureArray = new String[] {"image01.jpg","image02.jpg"}; // Array of 2

```
ticker = 0
if (ticker < 2)
    ticker++;  // STEP 1
else
    ticker = 0;
MessageBox.Show(pictureArray[ticker]);  // STEP 2

ticker    Image Shown
0          image02.jpg
1          image03.jpg   ?????
```

After checking, you are incrementing and then diaplying, so the displayed value is already 1 ahead of the ticker. 
To work out their are different ways :- you can replace the if clause (ticker < 21) to (ticker < pictureArray.Length -1). 
After incrementing to access the previous picture use pictureArray[ticker-1]. 
OR increment after displaying.
Have written a small code that works. The results are also shown.

```
    string[] pictureArray = new String[] {"image01.jpg","image02.jpg};
        int ticker = 0;
        do
        {
            if (ticker < pictureArray.Length - 1)
                ticker++;
            else
                ticker = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Ticker = " + ticker + " Image = " + pictureArray[ticker]);
        } while (true);

   Results :
 Ticker = 1 Image = image02.jpg
Ticker = 0 Image = image01.jpg
Ticker = 1 Image = image02.jpg
Ticker = 0 Image = image01.jpg
```

The below dispaly statements wil lalso result same as above :
       if (ticker == 0)
           Console.WriteLine("Ticker = " + ticker + " Image = " + pictureArray[0]);
        else
           Console.WriteLine("Ticker = " + ticker + " Image = " + pictureArray[ticker]);

If you can first dispaly and then increment or before incrementing save its value in other var and use that var to display that would result best instead of above ones.

```
int displayTicker = 0;
if (ticker < 2) {
    displayTicker =ticker;
    ticker++;
} else {
     displayTicker = ticker = 0;
}
MessageBox.Show (pictureArray[displayTicker]);
```

I believe this option will be the best. In such situation its better to have 2 vars instead of keeping one and having a check over it.

hope this helps.